# Error with action:@selector in app

Tags: ios, uiactionsheet

I'm creating an app were users should be able to report posts. I want an actionsheet when the user press the report button.
This is my code:

```
[self.avatarImageView.profileButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapReportButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and here is the didTapReportButtonAction code:

```
- (void)didTapReportButtonAction:(UIButton *)button {
    UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:@"Destructive" otherButtonTitles:@"Other1", @"Other2", nil];
    actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent;
    [actionSheet addButtonWithTitle:@"Add"];
    [actionSheet showInView:[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow];
}
```

But when I try to press the report button now, nothing happens.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: This is not an Xcode question.

Answer (score 1):

If avatarImageView is an UIImageView, its userinteraction property is false by default. 
this means the event won't called.

make sure `avatarImageView.userInteraction = YES`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
[actionSheet showInView:self.view];
```